# Random fragments issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

in my oncreate method I have this

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
myFragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.downPart, myFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

The problem is somethimes it trows forseclose message with this error

```
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.pakagename.pak1.MyFragmentsActivity: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

but it is just sometimes it is random sometimes I start my app and works good, and for example it works like 10 times in row works fine and then when I start it crashes...
after that again it works

I can't get it why sometimes it just crashes, is it possible to crash if there are some other apps run in background and somehow they slow my cpu or take a lot of memory, I really do not understand this random behavior.

Comment: shouldn't layoutFragment be myFragment. just an observation.

Comment: transaction.replace(R.id.downPart, myFragment);

Comment: yes it should be myFragment see my edits, but this is something that is missed while copying to stackoverflow forum in my project is called bottomf. never mind that is not my problem, if there was such bug then it would not work in any case... Note my app works just perfect most of the times I start it

Answer (score 4):

If you add a `Fragment` to the `FragmentManager`, Android will save their state and recreate them if the app's process is ever killed to reclaim memory, etc. 'Minimising' your app (pressing home) and then opening many other apps will cause this. When you return, it can only recreate your fragments if, as the error says, the fragment class name exists, is public, and has an empty public constructor.

You haven't shown us the code for `MyFragment`, but I am guessing one of these conditions is not true. In particular, it is likely that MyFragment is a (non-static) inner class of your activity. An inner class can only be instantiated within an instance of the outer class, but Android does this from another context when it recreates your fragment. This is why it is a problem to have a Fragment as an inner class.

To fix it, make sure MyFragment is either a static inner class, or its own class, and that the constructor is public (or not present; it will use the default one). A static inner class can exist without an instance of its outer class (and does not have access to any instance variables).

You can test this quite easily by pressing home after launching the app (`onSaveInstanceState` will be called), killing the process with DDMS, then relaunching your app. Alternatively, try your original steps whereby you open many other apps in-between.

Comment: Hi Antony, I have a different problem but it is recreated by the test described at the bottom of your answer. When I kill the process after pressing home, the fragments that were open are being overlayed on top of each other? They are added to the back stack so is this one of the issues?

Comment: @DiscoS2 I think all of these fragment issues are quite similar. You can create a question for it with some code and I will answer it if I can. Otherwise maybe someone else can help :)